# Mongoose Find Results and Async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I am writing a NodeJS script that will run every hour through Heroku's scheduler. I am quering the Mongo instance I have (mongohq/compose) and then doing something with those results. I am working with Mongoose.js and the find() command. This returns an array of results. With those results I need to perform additional queries as well as some additional async processing (sending email, etc).

Long story short, due to node's async nature I need to wait until all the processing is complete before I call `process.exit()`. If I do not the script stops early and the entire result set is not processed.

The problem is that I have a christmas tree effect of calls at this point (5 nested asnyc calls).

Normally I'd solve this with the async.js library but I'm having a problem seeing this through with this many callbacks.

How can I make sure this entire process finishes before exiting the script?

Here's the code that I'm working with (note: also using lodash below as `_`):

```
Topic.find({ nextNotificationDate: {$lte: moment().utc()}}, function (err, topics) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        finish();
    } else {

        _.forEach(topics, function (topic, callback) {

            User.findById(topic.user, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    // TODO: impl logging
                    console.error(err);
                } else {

                    // Create a new moment object (not moment.js, an actual moment mongoose obj)
                    var m = new Moment({ name: moment().format("MMM Do YY"), topic: topic});
                    m.save(function(err) {
                        if(err) {
                            // TODO: impl logging
                            console.error(err);
                        } else {

                            // Send an email via postmark
                            sendReminderTo(topic, user, m._id);

                            // Update the topic with next notification times.
                            // .. update some topic fields/etc
                            topic.save(function (err) {
                                if(err) {
                                    console.error(err);
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Topic updated.");
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
            console.log("User: " + topic.user);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: How is "christmas tree effect of calls" (aka [callback hell](http://google.com/search?q=callback+hell)) making the "process not finish before exiting"? Or are they two separate problems?

Comment: More or less just helping understand the problem. Callback hell is causing me to overthink/not understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Part of what is making your code confusing is the usage of `else` statements. If you return your errors, you won't need the else statement and save 4 lines of indentation for every callback. That in and of itself will make things drastically more readable.

Using async:

```
Topic.find({nextNotificationDate: {$lte: moment().utc()}}, function (err, topics) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return finish(err);
    }

    async.each(topics, function(topic, topicCallback) {

        async.auto({

            user: function (callback) {

                User.findById(topic.user, callback);
            },

            moment: function(callback) {

                var m = new Moment({name: moment().format("MMM Do YY"), topic: topic});
                m.save(callback);
            },

            topic: ["moment", "user", function (callback, results) {

                var m = results.moment;
                var user = results.user;

                sendReminderTo(topic, user, m._id);
                topic.save(callback);
            }]

        }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return topicCallback(err);
            }

            console.log("Topic updated.")
            return topicCallback();
        });
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return finish(err);
        }

        return finish();
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. However, the end result i'm after is how to execute everything an then when its done, know when to call process.exit(). :)

Comment: @Tony - That's what I was leaning towards but wasnt sure if that would do it for me.